Crear tabla SQL para realizar conteo de clics
Buen día, tengo una tabla SQL (tabla 1) en la que están alojados una cantidad dinámica de registros y en otra tabla (tabla 2) tengo los usuarios que también es dinámica. Lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que un determinado usuario de la tabla 2 consulte un registro de la tabla 1 se sume una "visualización" para que en otra sección de la aplicación pueda mostrar cuáles han sido los 10 registros más consultados por el usuario que está logueado en ese momento. La duda que tengo es cómo relaciono las dos tablas. No sé si crear una tercera tabla en la que las columnas correspondan a cada una de las filas de la tabla 1 y en las filas incluir a cada usuario de la tabla 2 e ir rellenando la tabla con cada vez que se visualiza un determinado registro o cuál sería la forma más óptima de hacerlo? Gracias.

Pues estás ante el típico problema de diseño de bases de datos con una cardinalidad M:N en el que sí que necesitas una nueva tabla3 que relacione ambas entidades. Y esto no es una opinión, lo sustenta una teoría muy asentada desde los años setenta del siglo pasado: Modelo Entidad-Relación, Peter Chen, 1976.

La forma de rellenar esa tabla es insertando un registro por cada visita que incluya el id del usuario y el id del registro, de forma que puedas contarlos en cualquier momento. Muy recomendable registrar ahí mismo fecha y hora de cada visualización para que puedas hacer tus estadísticas.
Sobre la consulta que quieres realizar, no tendrás más que usar GROUP BY para obtener tanto los registros más visitados, como los usuarios que más registros visitan.
No te recomiendo guardar únicamente el número de visitas de cada usuario, sino un registro por cada visita, por si tuvieras que depurar algún error.
Para que podamos continuar ayudándote, debes presentar algo que hayas intentado hacer por ti mismo.

Perfecto muchas gracias, no se me había ocurrido esa forma, es justo lo que necesitaba.
Al final dejé la tabla 3 así:
ID --- Fecha --- ID_usr --- ID_reg --- Vistas

Y para visualizar la información utilicé un SEELECT con GRUOP BY, lo filtré por el ID_usr que está logueado, lo ordené DESC por la cantidad de vistas y con LIMIT extraje las 50 más vistas. Mil gracias.
Tengo un problema similar con una tercera tabla de la misma aplicación es de precios para productos, la estructura es la siguiente:
ID ---- Producto ---- Valor
1 ----- Producto 1 ----- $10
2 ----- Producto 2 ----- $13
.
.
.

El problema es que cada usuario de la aplicación maneja una lista de precios diferentes para cada producto. Los productos son los mismos siempre, lo que cambia es el precio dependiendo del cliente. Cómo relacionaría la tabla usuarios con la de productos?
Podría hacerlo igual que la sugerencia que me diste en la respuesta anterior, sin embargo estaría multiplicando la cantidad de registros por cada usuario ya que son aproximadamente 600 productos y usuarios como 200, sería una tabla de 120.000 registros.
Yo había pensado en agregar una columna a la tabla productos por cada usuario pero no sé si eso esté bien en cuanto a diseño o no.
Muchas gracias por responder.

StackOverflow no es un foro. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para leer sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Esta respuesta, en realidad no responde a la pregunta, ni es un comentario. Puedes comentar en la respuesta de David, si es lo que quieres, o hacer una nueva pregunta, si la anterior ya quedó respondida, además de marcarla como aceptada.
